# Does html5 allow a plain ip address in action?

Tags: html

I am trying to post some data to my server,trouble is i do not have a fully qualified domain name or a sub domain.

Why does `action=http://127.0.0.1/index.php"` work and not `action="127.0.0.1"`

Answer (score 0):

because in `action=http://127.0.0.1/index.php"` there is the protocol of communication of HTTP and in the `127.0.0.1` is just the local adress of the computer